# How to hide an element and show a new element on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I have three images which, when clicked, display a hidden element containing text. However, I would like to ensure that the other 2 hidden elements are hidden when I display one. So, if I were to click on #img2, then #text2 would be displayed but #text1 and #text3 would be hidden. Also, this may just be a syntax error but when I tried to put all of my code under the script tag, it wouldn't work correctly. I'd also love to place all of the jquery in the script tag rather than using the onclick feature in HTML. I'm very new to jquery so all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<div id = "img1" onclick = "$('#text1').fadeIn(500)"></div>
<div id = "img2" onclick = "$('#text2').fadeIn(500)"></div>
<div id = "img3" onclick = "$('#text3').fadeIn(500)"></div>

<div id = "text1" hidden></div>
<div id = "text2" hidden></div>
<div id = "text3" hidden></div>

<script>
    /* TODO: Put all on-click code here */
</script>
```

Comment: Accept some answers to your questions.

Comment: please use jquery binding, when you are using jquery plugin already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a good practice to keep your code unobstrusive

HTML

```
<div id = "img1" class="img">One</div>
<div id = "img2" class="img">Two</div>
<div id = "img3" class="img">Three</div>

<div id = "text1" class="hidden">One</div>
<div id = "text2" class="hidden">Two</div>
<div id = "text3" class="hidden">Three</div>​
```

CSS

```
.hidden{display:none}​
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("div.img").on("click", function(){
       var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(-1);
       $(".hidden").hide();
       $("#text"+id).show();        
    });   
})​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EHxQE/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "img1" onclick = "$('.effect').hide();$('#text1').show()"></div>
<div id = "img2" onclick = "$('.effect').hide();$('#text2').show()"></div>
<div id = "img3" onclick = "$('.effect').hide();$('#text3').show()"></div>

<div id = "text1" class="effect" hidden></div>
<div id = "text2" class="effect" hidden></div>
<div id = "text3" class="effect" hidden></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">One</div>
<div id="div2">Two</div>
<div id="div3">Three</div>

<div id="texts">
    <div id="txt1">Text One</div>
    <div id="txt2">Text Two</div>
    <div id="txt3">Text Three</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){

    // hide every text div (all texts children)
    $( "#texts" ).children().hide();

    // this function hides every text child and than
    // fades in the desired one
    function hideAndShow( toShowSel ) {
        $( "#texts" ).children().hide();
        $( toShowSel ).fadeIn();
    }

    // registering the click event for the divs...
    $( "#div1" ).click( function(){
        hideAndShow( "#txt1"  );
    });

    $( "#div2" ).click( function(){
        hideAndShow( "#txt2"  );
    });

    $( "#div3" ).click( function(){
        hideAndShow( "#txt3"  );
    });
});
```

A live example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/FztUN/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/uptVT/

```
<div id = "img1" onclick = "$('.text').hide();$('#text1').show();">img1</div>
<div id = "img2" onclick = "$('.text').hide();$('#text2').show();">img2</div>
<div id = "img3" onclick = "$('.text').hide();$('#text3').show();">img3</div>

<div id="text1" class = "text" hidden>text1</div>
<div id="text2" class = "text" hidden>text2</div>
<div id="text3" class = "text" hidden>text3</div>

<script>
    /* TODO: Put all on-click code here */
</script>​
```